# Gerando json correto com p-dropdown primeng?

Tags: java, angular

Pessoal sou novo em Angular e estou com a seguinte situação utilizando a *API* em java:

Tenho a classe "Lancamento" onde a categoria *NÃO* é obrigatória (classe Categoria)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lancamento")
public class Lancamento {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long codigo;

    @NotNull
    private String descricao;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "codigo_categoria")
    private Categoria categoria;

    (...)
}
```

Quando vou cadastrar um lançamento na página criada com Angular utilizando a *API REST*, envio o *JSON* para esta *API* da seguinte forma:

```
{"descricao":"teste","categoria":{}}
```

Porém minha *API* retorna o seguinte erro (no java) devido não ter informado a categoria:

> ```
> TransientObjectException - object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
> ```

Fiz um teste no *Postman* enviando o *JSON* da seguinte forma para cadastrar o lançamento:

```
{"descricao":"teste"}
```

Desta forma consigo cadastrar, então fica a dúvida:

O erro é no angular que esta utilizando o componente `p-dropdown` do *primeng* da seguinte forma:

```
    <p-dropdown placeholder="Selecione..." [autoWidth]="false"
      [filter]="true" [options]="categorias"
      [(ngModel)]="lancamento.categoria.codigo" name="categoria"
      #categoria="ngModel"></p-dropdown>
```

Ou o erro é na declaração da categoria na classe *lancamento*?

Quando cadastro o lançamento informando a categoria, não há erros e o *JSON* é enviado da seguinte forma:

```
{"descricao":"teste","categoria":{"codigo":1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bruno, acredito que seu erro seja relacionado a Java e inclusive seja bem comum nas relações *Many-to-many*, um bom artigo é esse http://blog.caelum.com.br/transientobjectexception-lazyinitializationexception-e-outras-famosas-do-hibernate/. Há duas soluções possíveis: usar cascade no relacionamento (`cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST`) ou persistir todos os novos objetos separadamente.